# Xcode custom UI objects

Tags: iphone, objective-c, user-interface, xcode4

I am writing an application with xcode and I'm wondering if it is possible for me to customize the apperance of some of the UI objects as I don't think the current UI objects suite my application.

Comment: which objects do you want to customize?  You should be able to subclass almost anything to do customization (from changing the color of some piece of it all the way down to overriding and doing your own drawing... yikes!).

Comment: The Button, TableView, Navigation bar, Text field and Slider.

Comment: Of course you can customize, just about everything. Otherwise, everyones apps in the AppStore will look the same...Use your own graphics/artwork.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customise almost everything.

- The Button - use your own images as backgrounds
- TableView - images, custom cell content,
- Navigation bar - look at the UIAppearance methods, you can again set any image as the background, or set a tint colour
- Text field - this is kind of invisible except for the text, so you can give it a clear background and put it on top of anything you like
- Slider - you can set custom images for the track and thumb.

Comment: The apple class references are the best place to start.

Answer (score 0):

You can make custom classes of UIView or even UIControl to build up an entire new-looking UI system for yourself. If you don't want such radical changes, you can simply modify some properties of the various UI elements you have in UIKit, like `backgroundColor`, `alpha` etc.